# Filtering duplicated foreign key in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-5

I have this kind of data

```
id|no.BA|name|value|date
1 |22   |test|11111|30/11/2015
2 |22   |test|11144|31/12/2015
3 |34   |tttt|24455|31/12/2015
4 |44   |kkkk|33332|30/11/2015
5 |44   |kkkk|44433|31/12/2015
6 |44   |kkkk|67677|31/01/2016
```

no.BA is foreign key and id is my primary key, and in model I just use this belongsTo

```
 public function cuprimer(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Cuprimer','cu','id');
 }
```

While in my controller

```
$datas = PerkembanganCU::with('cuprimer')->orderBy('cu','asc')->get();
```

but what I intend to show is

```
id|no.BA|name|value|date
2 |22   |test|11144|31/12/2015
3 |34   |tttt|24455|31/12/2015
6 |44   |kkkk|67677|31/01/2016
```

So I don't need duplicated of no.BA 22 and 44 and only show the latest one according to date.

How to do that?

**update:**

Thanks to terminus for pointing to similar question
[in here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23835311/laravel-4-query-builder-groupby-max-date) but how to do it in eloquent way? since the solution using

```
  $rows = DB::table('papers')
               ->select(DB::raw('id, max(paper_update) as year,user_id'))
               ->groupBy('user_id')
               //->orderBy('paper_update', 'desc')
               ->get();
```

is there any eloquent way in laravel to improve belogsTo with max date?

**update2:**
So after doing some research I get until this point

```
$datas = Article::with('category')->groupby('no.BA')-get();
```

and it will only show each one of no.BA only one, but it's not complete yet.. since it only show the very first of each no.BA that i ever input/saved into database... i still need to specify that only show the latest or in this case the maximum of date...

So I almost there but not quite there yet...

**update3**

so a few days ago i thing i find the solution and also add it into answer section.

```
$datas = PerkembanganCU::with('cuprimer')
                ->orderBy('date','desc')->groupby('cu')
                ->whereRaw('date= (select max(`date`) from perkembangancu)')
                ->get();
```

but today after i tried to add real data i find there is one big flaw in this code. like say the data upthere... what it will show is only the one with max date

```
id|no.BA|name|value|date
6 |44   |kkkk|67677|31/01/2016
```

so please anybody that have expertise in sql query... please help me.. i stuck into every question in stackoverflow that claim the solution work... but in my case it is not working the way i want...

Comment: is your question similar to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23835311/laravel-4-query-builder-groupby-max-date ?

Comment: wow... yes i think it is pretty much the same, but in my case i get data from 2 table.... one is my primary table and another one is from cuprimer table, so how do i add 'max' parameter into my belongsto?

Comment: I have no experience with laravel; just wanted to point out the similar question in the hopes it would help :)

Comment: Here's a question how it to do it with plain ol' SQL http://stackoverflow.com/questions/612231/how-can-i-select-rows-with-maxcolumn-value-distinct-by-another-column-in-sql maybe you can use that to turn it into a Laravel solution

Comment: yes if it still using ol'SQL then i can do it... but i want to do it laravel way or specificly eloquent way....

Comment: I figured. Again, just hoping those answers could lead to the solution here.

Comment: Actually.... have you tried using [`having`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset)? Looks like you might be able to do, `->having('date', '=', 'MAX(date)')` after the `groupBy`

Comment: nope not working... getting error in sql...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that will do the work.

```
use App\Models\Cuprimer;
$rows = Cuprimer::groupBy('no.BA')
    ->havingRaw('COUNT(*) > 1')
    ->get();
```

If that doesn't work, try to remove the line with havingRaw().

Comment: Try include de orderBy('date', 'DESC') ($datas = Article::with('category')->orderBy('date', 'DESC')->groupby('no.BA')->get();)

Comment: hmm still no luck sir, it will show the first inputed into database field for each "no.BA" but not the latest by date... still get no answer for this problem.....

Comment: That is just a guess, but you could try to separate the calls, like: `$all = Article::with('category')->orderBy('date', 'DESC')->get();` / `$datas = $all->groupby('no.BA');`